# Applying additional oauth scopes in an omniauth initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, omniauth, scopes, coinbase-api

I am trying to apply the coinbase wallet API with oauth to use its send functionality. I have been able to connect to the API and use its endpoints, but whenever I try to use the send functionality, I am thrown the error `Invalid amount for meta[send_limit_amount]`. My omniauth initializer looks like this:

```
provider :coinbase, , ENV['CLIENT_ID'], ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'], 
scope: 'wallet:user:read wallet:user:email wallet:accounts:read wallet:transactions:send'
```

The reason for this error is because, in order to use the send functionality, coinbase requires additional parameter `meta[send_limit_amount]`. Where and how am I supposed to apply this additional scope?

UPDATE: So I've made some progress in that I am able to attach one meta scope to my initializer, which seems to be sticking (as shown when I print out the auth_info). This is the current state of my initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :coinbase, ENV['CLIENT_ID'], ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'], scope: 'wallet:user:read wallet:user:email wallet:accounts:read ', :meta => {'send_limit_currency' => 'BTC'}
end

# wallet:transactions:send
# :meta => {'send_limit_amount' => '0.0001'}
```

The problem now is that I cannot seem to figure the syntax necessary to add the `send_limit_amount` property to the oauth meta hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem with the following initializer;

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :coinbase, ENV['CLIENT_ID'], ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'],
  scope: 'wallet:user:read wallet:user:email wallet:accounts:read wallet:transactions:send',
  :meta => {'send_limit_amount' => 1}
end
```

Now, I need to either disable the two factor authentication or determine how to `Re-play the request with CB-2FA-Token header`